# AEM AUTHOR INSTANCE IS NOT RESPONDING

Tags: aem

my author instance crx/de is taking too long to open index.jsp, i was going through few solutions and some1 mentioned to go to CRXDE.ini and allocate more memory but i couldn't find the file. Can any1 suggest some other way to increase the performance of crx.

Comment: Have you checked error and access logs to see what is stuck and not responding? Memory allocation is done via JVM command line parameters so if restarts is an option and you are convinced that it's memory related then that would be something to consider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete or archive the older log files. Also you can archive the tar files or remove or compress the tar files. Also you can perform the tar compaction on regular intervals to prevent the build up of tar files. [Here](https://helpx.adobe.com/in/experience-manager/kb/AEM6-Maintenance-Guide.html) is a maintenance link for the same.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to increase memory would be to enter /crx-quickstart/bin directory and to edit file start.bat.
There you should find line

```
if not defined CQ_JVM_OPTS set CQ_JVM_OPTS=-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -Djava.awt.headless=true
```

Simply edit it by increasing CQ_JVM_OPTS and XX:MaxPermSize values.

However, it would better if you will run your AEM instance using bat file created by yourself. In such file you may declare Xms and Xmx Java options which say how much memory should be allocated. Look at belowed example:

```
%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java -Xms512M -Xmx2048M -jar cq-quickstart-6.5.0.jar -verbose -r author,devlocal
```